# Finding a value with the highest rank

Tags: python

I have the categories

```
Rank   Fruits:      Vegetable:    Years:
1      Apple        Lettuce       1900-1909      
2      Pineapple    Carrot        1900-1909
3      Orange       Potato        1900-1909
4      Banana       Beans         1900-1909
 Rank   Fruits:      Vegetable:    Years:
 1      Banana       Carrot        1910-1919      
 2      Orange       Potato        1910-1919
 3      Apple        Beans         1910-1919
 4      Pineapple    Lettuce       1910-1919
```

This is the data that I am given above.  I want to find when the fruit Banana was the most popular(aka when the rank is closest to 1). I also need to find when Carrot was the most popular.

For instance i would need it to show the result for Carrot would be 1910-1919 and Banana would be 1910-1919.

I have been messing around with this for hours.  I have tried putting them into sets and configuring it with keys and values but nothing Ive done has worked.  I would really appreciate the help.  Thanks!

```
def getHighRank(data):
    nameSet=()
    nameList=[]
    for names in data:
        nameList.append[1]
        nameList.append[2]
```

That is what I have so far. I tried fitting the fruits and vegetables into a single list.  I was thinking about converting this into a set, but im pretty clueless on what to do right now.

Comment: Please share what you have so that we can correct your mistakes.  Nobody is going to provide you a solution to this completely.

Comment: Are these two separate files?

Comment: not two seperate files all 1 file, ill print what i have so far one second plz

Comment: Your data doesn't make sense. It only gives a single value per year-range, which greatly limits its usefulness (e.g. 1900-1909 is always rank 1). It seems like you want three dimensions to your data table (date, rank and fruit/vegetable), but are trying to wedge it into two.

Comment: OMG completely messed up the years one sec plz, ill change it to what it is supposed to be

Comment: @user2105660 What is the structure of this file? csv?

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> d = {}
>>> with open('test.txt') as f:
        print f.read() # shows the file structure


Rank   Fruits:      Vegetable:    Years:
1      Apple        Lettuce       1900-1909      
2      Pineapple    Carrot        1900-1909
3      Orange       Potato        1900-1909
4      Banana       Beans         1900-1909
Rank   Fruits:      Vegetable:    Years:
1      Banana       Carrot        1910-1919      
2      Orange       Potato        1910-1919
3      Apple        Beans         1910-1919
4      Pineapple    Lettuce       1910-1919
>>> with open('test.txt') as f:
        for line in f:
            try:
                rank, fruit, vegetable, year = line.split()
                for k in (fruit, vegetable): # for both the fruit and veg
                    t = (rank, year) # tuple of rank and year
                    d[k] = min(d.get(k, t), t) # set it to the min (rank, year)
            except: # skip headers
                pass


>>> d['Apple'] # fast lookup
('1', '1900-1909')
>>> d['Apple'][1]
'1900-1909'
>>> d['Carrot'][1]
'1910-1919'
>>> d['Banana'][1]
'1910-1919'
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you could get the result for `"Carrot"`. You should be able to carry on from there:

```
with open('filename') as f:
    print min(row.split() for row in f if row[:1].isdigit() 
                                       and 'Carrot' in row)[3]
# prints: 1910-1919
```

Comment: This is likely to confuse OP if you look at his starting code

Comment: amen haha i dont understand this at all XD

Comment: @jamylak -- It is highly likely to be true, but aren't we all here to learn new things :)